# Git duplicate commits

Tags: git

After streamlining the history of a Git branch using `git rebase -i`, I'm having some trouble with remotes:

```
$ git push remote-name branch-name
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in ...
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://...'
$ git pull remote-name branch-name
...
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git mergetool
$ git commit -m "Merge"
```

Now the history of the branch is messed up, with my commits appearing twice (parallel lines in gitk) after some seemingly arbitrary point before my first commit. I've tried `git rebase -i`, but now it complains that it "Could not apply 123abc...". How do I get rid of the parallel commits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did something wrong, but I'm having a hard time understanding what. One possibility is that you rebased something that you already pushed, and then tried to push it again. This is a big no-no, you should never rebase something that you've already pushed to a remote repo, or you'll run into various issues. [Here's a short explanation of it](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: That's exactly it. Since I'm the only user of the target repo, I thought there would be a simple way of fixing this. Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: Oh...if you're the only user, then you can use the '-f' flag when you push, it'll just overwrite all the changes on the target repo. It's just not recommended as above.